# Getting 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command message when I was trying to execute the jar cvf Test.jar * command

Tags: java, jar, command

```
C:\Users\Desktop\ExploreWS\Explore>jar cvf Test.jar bin\com\test\Te
st1.class
'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please help to resolve this issue. Basically I'm trying to create a jar file without main class using window command prompt.

Receiving proper help message when I was trying to execute only `jar` command in command prompt

```
C:\Users\Desktop>jar
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] f
iles ...
Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -n  perform Pack200 normalization after creating a new archive
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -P  preserve leading '/' (absolute path) and ".." (parent directory) compone
nts from file names
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:
       jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
           files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
       jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

My requirement is that I want to create a jar file using project folder via command prompt but I don't have any Main class in my project. It's a Junit classes.

Comment: It means that in the first prompt `jar` is somehow not in the path, steps to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your response @RMPR. Issue is resolved now. I have mistakenly used different workspace path in command.